# What exactly is the type of lambda expression with a body?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Windows forms extension method `Invoke()` doesn't accept a lambda expression, without us having to first typecast it to a delegate type like `Action`. This makes me wonder, if lambda expression (with a body) is not explicitly a delegate nor an expression, what is its type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This makes me wonder, if lambda expression (with a body) is not explicitly a delegate nor an expression, what is its type?

It doesn't have a type in the normal sense of the word (i.e. a CLR type), just like `null` doesn't have a type. (Older versions of the C# specification had the concept of a "null type", but that was removed.)

Instead, it's an expression which is convertible to any compatible concrete delegate or expression tree type.

See section 7.1 of the C# 5 specification ("Expression Classification") for details - the relevant bullet points (out of the list of kinds of expression) are:

> - A null literal. An expression with this classification can be implicitly converted to a reference type or nullable type.
> - An anonymous function. An expression with this classification can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type or expression tree type.

Comment: Great explanation! Seeing that it is none other than @JonSkeet, I have no choice but to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Delegate` is an `abstract` base class for all the delegates(`MulticastDelegate` comes in between). Lambda can't be converted to `Delegate` type  as it can't be instantiated, and it doesn't have any signature.

So, You need to be more specific in saying what delegate type you're interested.

> what is its type?

It has no type, it can be converted to any delegate type or `Expression<TDelegate>` type if the signature is compatible.

Comment: That explains the error, but it doesn't answer the question.